# How to add Headers to multiple sheets in a workbook using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, reporting, apache-poi, batch-processing

I have created a Batch Reporting using Apache POI. I need to know how to add Headers to both sheets. I used getHeader() but that adds same Headers for both sheets and I need to add different headers to both sheets. My code is following.

Excel Writer:

```
public class ExcelWriter {

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ExcelWriter.class.getName());

private HSSFWorkbook excel;

public ExcelWriter() {
    excel = new HSSFWorkbook();
}

public HSSFWorkbook getWorkbook() {
    return excel;   
}

public void writeExcelFile(String filename, String[] columns, Object[][] data, HSSFCellStyle[] styles, 
        HSSFCellStyle columnsStyle, String[] header, String[] footer) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

    HSSFSheet sheet = excel.createSheet("Daily Screening");
    HSSFSheet sheet1 = excel.createSheet("Parcel Return");

    int numHeaderRows = header.length; 
    createHeader(sheet,header,columns.length, 0);

    createColumnHeaderRow(sheet,columns,numHeaderRows,columnsStyle);

    int rowCtr1 = numHeaderRows;
    for( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {         

        if (i > data.length -2) 
            ++rowCtr1;
        else 
            rowCtr1 = rowCtr1 + 2;

        createRow(sheet, data[i], rowCtr1, styles);
    }
    int totalRows = rowCtr1 + 1;
    createHeader(sheet1,footer,columns.length, totalRows);


    excel.write(out);
    out.close();
}

private void createHeader(HSSFSheet sheet1, String[] header, int columns, int rowNum) {     

    for( int i = 0; i < header.length ; i++ ) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet1.createRow(i + rowNum);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
        String text = header[i];
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(text);            
        HSSFCellStyle style = excel.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        HSSFFont arialBoldFont = excel.createFont();
        arialBoldFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        arialBoldFont.setFontName("Arial");
        arialBoldFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        style.setFont(arialBoldFont);

        if (!isEmpty(header[i]) && rowNum < 1) {
            style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(style);           
        sheet1.addMergedRegion( new Region(i+rowNum,(short)0,i+rowNum,(short)(columns-1)) );
    }
}   


private HSSFRow createColumnHeaderRow(HSSFSheet sheet, Object[] values, int rowNum, HSSFCellStyle style) {

    HSSFCellStyle[] styles = new HSSFCellStyle[values.length];

    for( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
        styles[i] = style;
    }

    return createRow(sheet,values,rowNum,styles);
}

private HSSFRow createRow(HSSFSheet sheet1, Object[] values, int rowNum, HSSFCellStyle[] styles) {

    HSSFRow row = sheet1.createRow(rowNum);

    for( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) i);
        cell.setCellStyle(styles[i]);

        try{
            Object o = values[i];

            if( o instanceof String ) { 
                String text = String.valueOf(o);
                cell.setCellValue(text);
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            }
            else if (o instanceof Double) {
                Double d = (Double) o;                  
                cell.setCellValue(d.doubleValue());
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);                   
            }
            else if (o instanceof Integer) {
                Integer in = (Integer)o;                    
                cell.setCellValue(in.intValue());                   
            }
            else if (o instanceof Long) {
                Long l = (Long)o;                   
                cell.setCellValue(l.longValue());
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);                   
            }
            else if( o != null ) {
                String text = String.valueOf(o);
                cell.setCellValue(text);
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return row;
}

public boolean isEmpty(String str) {

    if(str.equals(null) || str.equals("")) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

Report Generator which includes Headers, footer, and columns:

```
public class SummaryReportGenerator extends ReportGenerator {

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SummaryReportGenerator.class.getName());

public SummaryReportGenerator(String reportDir, String filename) {
    super( reportDir + filename + ".xls", reportDir + filename + ".pdf");       
}

public String[] getColumnNames() {
    String[] columnNames = {"ISC\nCode", "Total\nParcels", "Total\nParcel Hit\n Count",
            "Filter Hit\n%", "Unanalyzed\nCount", "Unanalyzed\n%",
            "Name\nMatch\nCount", "Name\nMatch\n%", "Pended\nCount",
            "Pended\n%", "E 1 Sanction\nCountries\nCount", "E 1 Sanction\nCountries\n%", "Greater\nthat\n$2500\nCount", "Greater\nthat\n$2500\n%",
            "YTD\nTotal Hit\nCount", "YTD\nLong Term\nPending", "YTD\nLong Term\n%"};
    return columnNames;
}


public HSSFCellStyle getColumnsStyle(HSSFWorkbook wrkbk) {
    HSSFCellStyle style = wrkbk.createCellStyle();
    style.setWrapText(true);        
    style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    HSSFFont timesBoldFont = wrkbk.createFont();
    timesBoldFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    timesBoldFont.setFontName("Arial");
    style.setFont(timesBoldFont);
    return style;
}

public Object[][] getData(Map map) {    
    int rows = map.size();// +  1 + // 1 blank row   1;  // 1 row for the grand total;      
    int cols = getColumnNames().length;

    Object[][] data = new Object[rows][cols];       
    int row = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < map.size(); i++ ){

        try{
            SummaryBean bean = (SummaryBean)map.get(new Integer(i));

            data[row][0] = bean.getIscCode();
            data[row][1] = new Long(bean.getTotalParcelCtr());
            data[row][2] = new Integer(bean.getTotalFilterHitCtr());
            data[row][3] = bean.getFilterHitPrctg();
            data[row][4] = new Integer(bean.getPendedHitCtr());
            data[row][5] = bean.getPendedHitPrctg();
            data[row][6] = new Integer(bean.getTrueHitCtr());
            data[row][7] = new Integer(bean.getRetiredHitCtr());                
            data[row][8] = new Integer(bean.getSanctCntryCtr());
            data[row][9] = new Integer(bean.getC25Ctr());
            data[row][10] = new Integer(bean.getCnmCtr());
            data[row][11] = new Integer(bean.getCndCtr());              
            data[row][12] = new Integer(bean.getCnlCtr());
            data[row][13] = new Integer(bean.getCneCtr());
            data[row][14] = new Integer(bean.getVndCtr());
            data[row][15] = new Integer(bean.getCilCtr());
            data[row][16] = new Integer(bean.getHndCtr());
            data[row][17] = new Integer(bean.getCnrCtr());
            ++row;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {                    
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }           
    }   

    return data;
}

public String[] getHeader(String startDate, String endDate) {
    Date today = new Date();
    String reportDateFormat = Utils.formatDateTime(today, "MM/dd/yyyyHH.mm.ss");

    String nowStr = Utils.now(reportDateFormat);
    String[] header = {"","EXCS Daily Screening Summary Report ","",
              "for transactions processed for the calendar date range", 
              "from " + startDate  + " to " + endDate,
              "Report created on " + nowStr.substring(0,10)+ " at " 
              +  nowStr.substring(10)};
    return header;
}

public HSSFCellStyle[] getStyles(HSSFWorkbook wrkbk) {
    int columnSize = getColumnNames().length;
    HSSFCellStyle[] styles = new HSSFCellStyle[columnSize];

    HSSFDataFormat format = wrkbk.createDataFormat();
    for (int i=0; i < columnSize; i++){
        styles[i] = wrkbk.createCellStyle();
        if (i == 0){
            styles[i].setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        }else{
            styles[i].setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        }
        if (i == 1 || i == 2){
            styles[i].setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#,###,##0"));
        }
        HSSFFont timesFont = wrkbk.createFont();            
        timesFont.setFontName("Arial");
        styles[i].setFont(timesFont);
    }
    return styles;
}

public String[] getFooter() {

    String[] header = {"","Parcel Return Reason Code Reference","",
                  "DPM = Sender and/or recipient matches denied party",
                  "HND = Humanitarian exception not declared",
                  "CNM = Content not mailable under export laws",
                  "VND = Value of content not declared",
                  "CNR = Customer non-response",
                  "C25 = Content Value greater than $2500",
                  "CIL = Invalid license",
                  "C30 =  More than one parcel in a calendar month",
                  "CNL = Content description not legible",
                  "CNE = Address on mailpiece not in English",
                  "RFN = Requires full sender and addressee names",
                  "DGS = Dangerous goods",
                  "R29 = RE-used 2976 or 2976A",
                  "ANE = PS Form 2976 or 2976A not in English",
                  "ICF = Incorrect Customs Declaration Form used",
                  "DPR = Declaration of purpose required",
                  "ITN = Internal Transaction Number (ITN), Export Exception/Exclusion Legend (ELL), or Proof of Filing Citation (PFC) is required",
                  "OTH = Other","",};
    return header;
}
```

}

Report Generator Abstract class

```
public void generateExcelReport(Map map, String startDate, String endDate) throws IOException {
    ExcelWriter writer = new ExcelWriter();
    writer.writeExcelFile( getXlsFilename(),  getColumnNames(), getData(map), 
            getStyles(writer.getWorkbook()), getColumnsStyle(writer.getWorkbook()),
            getHeader(startDate, endDate), getFooter());
```

Report Driver:

```
public class ReportDriver {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ReportDriver.class.getName());

public static void main (String args[]){

    if (args.length == 0) {
        log.error("Usage - ReportDriver [Day|Week|Month|Year]");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String reportPeriod = args[0];

    log.info("Begin Prior " + reportPeriod + " Report");

    String dir = "c:\\excsbatch\\report\\";

    Dates dates = new Dates();
    dates.setDates(reportPeriod);
    String startDate = dates.getStartDate();
    String endDate = dates.getEndDate();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    String fileName = "prior" + reportPeriod + "Report" + timeStamp;

    SummaryDAO dao = new SummaryDAO();
    Map map = dao.extractData(startDate, endDate);
    SummaryReportGenerator report = new SummaryReportGenerator(dir, fileName);

    try {
        report.generateExcelReport(map, startDate, endDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }   
    log.info("End Prior " + reportPeriod + " Report");
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not getting it. Why not have a different set of logic for the two sheets, pass sheet 1 to the first set, sheet 2 to the second, then you end up with different headers...

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Are you talking about the logic in excel writer code or the Report Generator Header code logic?

Comment: if you pass the same Start Date and End Date values to getHeader, of course it will return the same header, what were you expecting?

Comment: By the way, in your code, you never call `getHeader`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Miguel.  I didnt copy past all the classes with my question if you like I can do that right now.  Im really confused and need to figure it out asap. If I copy the entire code can you try to help me?